# Error: Cannot find module './models/userSchema'

Tags: backend

getting error, here is the image of my folder path:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqEZf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2qjN.png)

pls help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your got '../models/userSchema' while they are in the same folder try './models/userSchema'